# Coredump of qt application after qt upgrade

Tags: c++, linux, qt, embedded, yocto

After a Yocto upgrade to warrior and with this an qt upgrade from 5.9.7 to 5.12.8 our qt qml application crashes on the device if the user scrolls (keyboard event) through a listview. It crashes in QV4::MarkStack::drain (QmlEngine GarbageCollector) and we have no idea where the problem could be.

Any advise how to find such an error?

Here is a backtrace:

```
Thread 1 (LWP 516):
#0  0x0000001c in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0xb695a9d0 in QV4::MarkStack::drain (this=this@entry=0xbee86804) at ../../include/QtQml/5.12.8/QtQml/private/../../../../../../git/src/qml/memory/qv4heap_p.h:73
        h = <optimized out>
#2  0xb69b9904 in QV4::PersistentValueStorage::mark (this=<optimized out>, markStack=markStack@entry=0xbee86804) at /usr/src/debug/qtdeclarative/5.12.8+gitAUTOINC+101799f8ac-r0/git/src/qml/jsruntime/qv4persistent.cpp:243
        p = 0xb0078000
#3  0xb695b4fe in QV4::MemoryManager::collectRoots (this=this@entry=0x1099c68, markStack=markStack@entry=0xbee86804) at /usr/src/debug/qtdeclarative/5.12.8+gitAUTOINC+101799f8ac-r0/git/src/qml/memory/qv4mm.cpp:871
No locals.
#4  0xb695b678 in QV4::MemoryManager::mark (this=this@entry=0x1099c68) at /usr/src/debug/qtdeclarative/5.12.8+gitAUTOINC+101799f8ac-r0/git/src/qml/memory/qv4mm.cpp:912
        markStack = {top = 0xaa8b7084, base = 0xaa8b7000, limit = 0xaaa37000, engine = 0x158efb8}
#5  0xb695cbb0 in QV4::MemoryManager::runGC (this=0x1099c68) at /usr/src/debug/qtdeclarative/5.12.8+gitAUTOINC+101799f8ac-r0/git/src/qml/memory/qv4mm.cpp:1047
        gcBlocker = {varRef = @0x1099d2c, oldValue = false}
#6  0xb695e1e6 in QV4::MemoryManager::allocate (size=32, allocator=0x1099c70, this=0x1099c68) at ../../include/QtQml/5.12.8/QtQml/private/../../../../../../git/src/qml/memory/qv4mm_p.h:328
        didGCRun = false
        didGCRun = <optimized out>
        m = <optimized out>
#7  QV4::MemoryManager::allocData (this=0x1099c68, size=32) at /usr/src/debug/qtdeclarative/5.12.8+gitAUTOINC+101799f8ac-r0/git/src/qml/memory/qv4mm.cpp:797
        m = <optimized out>
#8  0xb695e284 in QV4::MemoryManager::allocObjectWithMemberData (this=this@entry=0x1099c68, vtable=vtable@entry=0xb6be4358 <QV4::Object::static_vtbl>, nMembers=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/qtdeclarative/5.12.8+gitAUTOINC+101799f8ac-r0/git/src/qml/memory/qv4mm.cpp:809
        size = <optimized out>
        o = <optimized out>
#9  0xb6a690de in QV4::MemoryManager::allocateObject<QV4::Object> (ic=<optimized out>, this=<optimized out>) at ../../include/QtQml/5.12.8/QtQml/private/../../../../../../git/src/qml/jsruntime/qv4object_p.h:142
        o = <optimized out>
        o = <optimized out>
#10 QV4::MemoryManager::allocateObject<QV4::Object> (ic=0xaaab80a8, this=<optimized out>) at ../../include/QtQml/5.12.8/QtQml/private/../../../../../../git/src/qml/memory/qv4mm_p.h:201
No locals.
#11 QV4::MemoryManager::allocateObject<QV4::Object> (this=<optimized out>) at ../../include/QtQml/5.12.8/QtQml/private/../../../../../../git/src/qml/memory/qv4mm_p.h:211
        scope = <optimized out>
        ic = <optimized out>
        scope = <optimized out>
        ic = <optimized out>
#12 QV4::MemoryManager::allocate<QV4::Object> (this=<optimized out>) at ../../include/QtQml/5.12.8/QtQml/private/../../../../../../git/src/qml/memory/qv4mm_p.h:244
        scope = <optimized out>
        t = <optimized out>
        scope = <optimized out>
        t = <optimized out>
#13 QV4::ExecutionEngine::newObject (this=this@entry=0x158efb8) at /usr/src/debug/qtdeclarative/5.12.8+gitAUTOINC+101799f8ac-r0/git/src/qml/jsruntime/qv4engine.cpp:720
No locals.
#14 0xb69b8bf8 in QV4::ExecutionContext::createMutableBinding (this=<optimized out>, name=0xaaab8090, deletable=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/qtdeclarative/5.12.8+gitAUTOINC+101799f8ac-r0/git/src/qml/jsruntime/qv4context.cpp:163
        c = 0xaa5029c0
        scope = {engine = 0x158efb8, mark = 0xaaab8098}
        activation = {ptr = 0xaaab8098}
        ctx = {ptr = 0xaaab80a0}
        id = <optimized out>
        desc = <optimized out>
        attrs = {{m_all = 112 'p', {m_flags = 0 '\000', m_mask = 7 '\a'}, {m_type = 0 '\000', m_writable = 0 '\000', m_enumerable = 0 '\000', m_configurable = 0 '\000', type_set = 1 '\001', writable_set = 1 '\001', enumerable_set = 1 '\001', configurable_set = 0 '\000'}}}
#15 0xb6a74aae in QV4::Runtime::method_declareVar (engine=0x158efb8, deletable=<optimized out>, nameIndex=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/qtdeclarative/5.12.8+gitAUTOINC+101799f8ac-r0/git/src/qml/jsruntime/qv4value_p.h:186
        scope = {engine = 0x158efb8, mark = 0xaaab8090}
        name = {ptr = 0xaaab8090}
#16 0xa9b6e47c in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Comment: not sure this is the place to ask. You should at least give the backtrace.

Comment: I included a backtrace. Any other ideas, where to ask?

Comment: can you run your application in valgrind? looks like a double free